# Export Outlook calendar - with powershell - to iCalendar Anonymized

Tags: outlook, time-series, export, icalendar

Normal calendar entries are exported fine and anomyzed, but Appointment series will not been exported. Has anybody an idea how this could be solved without 3party tools?

My code looks like this:

```
# Create Outlook application
$outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

# Open calendar folder (default calendar)
$calendar = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(9)

# Export file path
$exportFilePath = "C:\AnonymizedCalendar.ics"

# Number of days before and after the current date for the time frame
$daysBefore = 10  # Adjust the number of days before
$daysAfter = 60   # Adjust the number of days after

# Calculate the start and end dates based on the days before and after
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysBefore)
$endDate = (Get-Date).AddDays($daysAfter)

# Open the export file and add the iCalendar header
$icalHeader = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0"
$icalFooter = "END:VCALENDAR"
$icalData = $icalHeader

# Function to anonymize text
function Anonymize-Text($text) {
    return "Work"  # Replace "Work" with your desired anonymization
}

# Function to convert DateTime to iCalendar format
function Convert-To-iCalendarDateTime($dateTime) {
    return $dateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")
}

# Iterate through all calendar events and export them
$calendar.Items | ForEach-Object {
    $item = $_
    if ($item.Start -le $endDate -and $item.End -ge $startDate) {
        $subject = Anonymize-Text($item.Subject)  # Anonymize the text
        $uid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()  # Unique UID for the event

        if ($item.IsRecurring) {
            $recurrence = $item.GetRecurrencePattern()
            $range = $recurrence.GetRecurrenceRange()
            $start = $range.StartDate
            $end = $range.EndDate

            $occurrences = $recurrence.GetOccurrence()

            foreach ($occurrence in $occurrences) {
                $occurrenceDate = $occurrence.Start
                if ($occurrenceDate -ge $startDate -and $occurrenceDate -le $endDate) {
                    $start = Convert-To-iCalendarDateTime($occurrence.Start)
                    $end = Convert-To-iCalendarDateTime($occurrence.End)

                    $icalEvent = "BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:$uid
DTSTAMP:$((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"))
DTSTART:$start
DTEND:$end
SUMMARY:$subject
END:VEVENT"

                    # Add anonymized iCalendar data to the iCalendar header
                    $icalData += "`r`n$icalEvent"
                }
            }
        } else {
            $start = Convert-To-iCalendarDateTime($item.Start)
            $end = Convert-To-iCalendarDateTime($item.End)

            $icalEvent = "BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:$uid
DTSTAMP:$((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"))
DTSTART:$start
DTEND:$end
SUMMARY:$subject
END:VEVENT"

            # Add anonymized iCalendar data to the iCalendar header
            $icalData += "`r`n$icalEvent"
        }
    }
}

# Add iCalendar footer
$icalData += "`r`n$icalFooter"

# Write iCalendar data to the file
$icalData | Out-File -FilePath $exportFilePath -Encoding utf8
```

- Google
- ChatGPT
  etc.

the problem is, it should run without admin rights and with default windows tools. So no 3rd party tools.